# How to control dynamically added input type file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I am trying to get the size of a dynamically added input type file.

**JSP**

```
 <div>
    <button type="button"  id="appendTab" name="appendTab">Append</button>
    <button type="button"  id="deleteTab" name="deleteTab">Delete</button>  
 </div>
 <table id="bnspTable" class="table">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th style="width:8%;">check</th>
             <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:82%">FileName</th>
             <th style="text-align:center; width:10%">FileSize</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fileTbody">
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

**JS**

```
 $("#appendTab").on("click",function(){
        page.appendTab();
 })
 page.appendTab = function(){
    var cnt = $("#fileTbody tr").length + 1;

    var addHtml = '<tr class="addFile" style="text-align:center;">';
    addHtml += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="P_CHECK" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></td>';
    addHtml += '<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="uploadName" size="70" readonly><input type="file" id= "file_nm' +cnt+'" name="P_ORG_FILE_NM" class="fileNM" onchange="sizeCheck()"></td>';
    addHtml += '<td><input type="text" name="fileSize" readonly size="10"></td>';
    addHtml += '</tr>';
    $("#bnspTable").find('tbody').append(addHtml);
  }; //Ability to add rows to tbody

 sizeCheck = function(){
    $(document).on('change','.fileNM',(function(){

        var file = this.files[0];
        var fileName = file.name;
        var fileSize = file.size;
        $("input[name='fileSize']").val(fileSize);
    }));
  /* 
  At first,i can do it by giving a class, but it will be overwritten with the file size added 
  later.*/
};
```

At first,i can do it by giving a class, but it will be overwritten with the file size added 
      later.

I'm trying to control by id, but it's not working, so I'm going to do it by name.
When i add a file, i want to put the size of the file into input with name = "fileSize"

However, I don't know how many files will be added, so I can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main issues here. Firstly as you're correctly using a delegated event handler here you only need to instantiate it once, not within the `sizeCheck()` function. Doing that will mean the handler is bound multiple times which is the last thing you need. Therefore move the `on()` call outside of that function and remove `onclick` from your HTML.

The second issue is that you're selecting *all* `input[name='fileSize']` elements in the change handler, whereas you only need to find the one related to the file input which triggered the event. To do that use jQuery's DOM traversal methods, `closest()` and `find()` in this case.

With all that said, try this:

```js
let page = {};
page.appendTab = function() {
  var addHtml = '<tr class="addFile">';
  addHtml += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="P_CHECK"></td>';
  addHtml += '<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="uploadName" size="70" readonly><input type="file"  name="P_ORG_FILE_NM" class="fileNM"></td>';
  addHtml += '<td><input type="text" name="fileSize" readonly size="10"></td>';
  addHtml += '</tr>';
  $("#bnspTable").find('tbody').append(addHtml);
};

$("#appendTab").on("click", function() {
  page.appendTab();
})

$(document).on('change', '.fileNM', (function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var fileName = file.name;
  var fileSize = file.size;
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="fileSize"]').val(fileSize);
}));
```

```css
.addFile {
  text-align: center;
}

.addFile input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

tr th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 8%;
}

tr th:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  width: 82%
}

tr th:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" id="appendTab" name="appendTab">Append</button>
  <button type="button" id="deleteTab" name="deleteTab">Delete</button>
</div>
<table id="bnspTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>check</th>
      <th colspan="2">FileName</th>
      <th>FileSize</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="fileTbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

As an aside, don't use incremental `id` attributes. It's an anti-pattern as it creates more complex and verbose code which is harder to maintain. You don't need them at all anyway when using DOM traversal correctly. In addition, don't use inline `style` attributes. Put all style rules in an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

you can probably bind an event after adding html in to DOM.
below is updated code.

```js
var page={}
$("#appendTab").on("click",function(){
        page.appendTab();
 })
 page.appendTab = function(){
    var cnt = $("#fileTbody tr").length + 1;
    var addHtml = '<tr class="addFile" style="text-align:center;">';
    addHtml += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="P_CHECK" style="width:15px; height:15px;"></td>';
    addHtml += '<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="uploadName" style="width:100px;" id="file_' +cnt+'"  size="70" readonly><input type="file" id= "file_nm' +cnt+'" name="P_ORG_FILE_NM" class="fileNM"></td>';
    addHtml += '<td><input type="text" name="fileSize" readonly size="10" id="size_inpt' +cnt+'"></td>';
    addHtml += '</tr>';
    $("#bnspTable").find('tbody').append(addHtml);
    $("#file_nm" +cnt).on("change",function(){
         debugger
         var file = this.files[0];
         
        var fileName = file.name;
        var fileSize = file.size;
        $("#size_inpt"+cnt).val(fileSize);
        $("#file_" +cnt).val(fileName)
    })
  }; //Ability to add rows to tbody
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button type="button"  id="appendTab" name="appendTab">Append</button>
    <button type="button"  id="deleteTab" name="deleteTab">Delete</button>  
 </div>
 <table id="bnspTable" class="table">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th style="width:8%;">check</th>
             <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:82%">FileName</th>
             <th style="text-align:center; width:10%">FileSize</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fileTbody">
    </tbody>
 </table>
```